# C# property constraints

Tags: c#, properties

I have a following statement:

```
public int aValue { get; set; }
public int func() { return someNonConstantValue; }
```

is there a way to constraint it to the range from `-5` to what `func()` returns?
I could use `Math.Clamp` but if I define the setter will I also need to provide the getter?

Comment: I have _no idea_ what you are talking about. Can you explain this as if we knew nothing about what you want to do?

Comment: _" to constraint it"_ - what is "it" ?

Comment: Are you trying to return aValue and potentially have a value return at least -5? In that case you return Math.Max(-5, aValue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you provide a setter you will also need a custom getter. By this should not be a problem:

```
private int _aValue;
public int aValue
{
   get => _aValue;
   set
   {
     int upperLimit = func();
     if(value < -5 || value > upperLimit )
     {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value", "should be between -5 and " + upperLimit);
     }
     _aValue = value;
   }
}
```

Comment: Side note: I suggest a little brushing: `nameof(value)` instead of `"value"` to get rid of magic string; `$"Should be between -5 and {upperLimit}"` to make string more readable.